# Cardano Data for Data Analytics and Data Visualisation

Tags: wallet, ada, api, metadata

Where can I get Cardano raw data or formatted data (e.g. no. of wallets, ADA price, etc) that I can use for data science, analytics and visualisation?

Answer (score 2):

there are providers such as

https://api.koios.rest/#overview

and

https://blockfrost.io/